# Create-react-app service worker not functioning

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app

I am working on a React progressive web app built from create-react-app, and am attempting to register a service worker.

However, after following the documentation on create-react-app which merely says to change serviceWorker.unregister() to serviceWorker.register(), doesn't register anything.

Even from a fresh create-react-app project this still doesn't work.

The documentation seems very lean for this topic, is there anything else I need to do to register the default service worker generated by create-react-app?

Comment: Did you read/follow all in here: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app

Comment: @adam show your registerServiceWorker.js

Comment: @akrion Yes I followed the steps on that page, its just changing unregister() to register() unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @AkshayMulgavkar my register service work file is the exact same that CRA spits out. I have not touched it at all

Comment: I faced the same problem on newly created-react-app. But not sure what happened, I closed and reopened the chrome instance and serviceWorker got registered

Answer (score 8):

step 1 :

```
npm i workbox-cli
```

step 2 : create `workbox-config.js` file in your project folder

step 3 : add

```
module.exports = {
  globDirectory: './public/',
  globPatterns: ['\*\*/\*.{html,js}'],
  swDest: './public/sw.js',
  clientsClaim: true,
  skipWaiting: true
};
```

step 4: update your `serviceWorker.js` file with

`` const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/sw.js` ``

step 5: update your `package.json` file

```
"scripts": {
  // ...    
  "build": " workbox generateSW && react-scripts build",
  // ...
}
```

Then build and serve.

read more https://medium.com/@arafatahmedtanimcsedu57/progressive-web-apps-with-create-react-app-ca0c955ab798

Comment: NP. Question: is the code in step 4 missing a closing backtick?

Comment: i think the first backtick was misleading  then I remove it

Comment: Why would I add workbox manually? I thought it's built into CRA

Comment: Oh man thanks so much for this, I used to expect create-react-app to just have PWA by default... was surprised when my "PWA" wasn't actually working. In my case I was partially copying an old project I had that was a PWA so I already added in the serviceWorker.js file/import/registered it to index.js then applied steps above.

Comment: @JacobDavidC.Cunningham read more <https://medium.com/@arafatahmedtanimcsedu57/progressive-web-apps-with-create-react-app-ca0c955ab798>

Comment: This answer is misleading. It does not make use of service-worker.js but creates a new service worker at sw.js

Answer (score 7):

If you bootstrapped your app using `create-react-app`, then go `index.js` and change the line `serviceWorker.unregister()` to `serviceWorker.register()`

Then build the app using `npm run build` and run the app from `build` directory using an HTTP server like `serve` or `http-server`.

Open **DevTools** and got to **Application** tab, you'll see your service worker running.

Comment: How come I need to build the app and run it in production mode for the service worker to `work`? Shouldn't it also work with react-scripts start?

Comment: `react-scripts start` won't start Service Worker. The service Worker requires an HTTPS connection to work. First, build the application after doing the above changes using `npm run build`. Then deploy / host to a HTTPS origin. You can see SW working.

Comment: thats correct, its needs https. So deploy it somewhere first :)

Comment: service worker should work from localhost fine, but for some reason the react dev server doesn't serve the file at all

Comment: Can we use it in dev environment? Instead of building production build

Answer (score 3):

If you are not seeing your service worker active in the applications tab of dev tools then you can try the following:

1. Ensure you are viewing the application on either a "**localhost**" or an **HTTPS** url, anything else will not work.
2. Try running the build in production mode (instead of dev) by running this in your console:

> npm run prod

Then if you want to run a dev server you can follow that with:

> serve -s build

and access your website on the URL specified in the response (likely localhost:5000).

Comment: This actually works for me. I am using the ip address instead of the localhost thats why its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while I was tinkering with some service workers simultaneously, and even though I created a new create-react-app, changed `unregister` to `register`, it still didn't work. It was **first when I restarted chrome**, built my app, and served it with `serve` that it actually started working.

I also removed the if production condition to enable it everywhere.